# EXC_BAD_ACCESS calling c++ class method from NSTimer

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos

Running into issues trying to mix c++ and objective-c when building cocoa app using Xcode4.
The issue is when I use NSTimer to call handleFrame function, which calls a virtual function of a class.

Here is what i am trying to do: 
1. Create a monitor;
2. Create a handler;
3. Assign handler to monitor (init function)
4. Call monitor->update() that is expected to call handler's virtual method.
5. Code works as expected in applicationDidFinishLaunching function, however NSTimer is causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in handleFrame.

```
    //
    //  AppDelegate.h
    //  Concept5
    //

    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #include "monitor.h"
    #include "Derived.h"

    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
    {
        Monitor *monitor;`enter code here`
        NSTimer *gameTimer;
    }

    @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

    - (void)handleFrame:(NSTimer *)timer;

    @end

AppDelegate implementation (.mm)

    //
    //  AppDelegate.mm
    //  Concept5
    //

    #import "AppDelegate.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate


    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [super dealloc];
    }

    - (id) init {
        self = [super init];
        if(self) {
            monitor = new Monitor();
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)handleFrame:(NSTimer *)timer {
         monitor->update();
    }

    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        Derived derived;

        monitor->init(derived);
        monitor->update();

        gameTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(handleFrame:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES] retain];


        monitor->update();

    }
    @end





    //
    //  Monitor.cpp
    //  Concept5
    //

    #include "Monitor.h"


    void Monitor::init (Base& handler)
    {
        _handler = &handler;
    }

    void Monitor::update()
    {
        if (_handler != NULL)
        {
            _handler->speak(); // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.
        }
    }

//
//  Monitor.h
//  Concept5

#ifndef __Concept5__Monitor__
#define __Concept5__Monitor__

#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"

class Monitor
{
private:
    Base* _handler;
public:
    void init (Base& handler);
    void update();
};

#endif /* defined(__Concept5__Monitor__) */

    //
    //  Base.cpp
    //  Concept5


    #include "Base.h"

    void Base::speak()
    {
        std::cout << "Base speaks" << std::endl;
    }


    //
    //  Base.h
    //  Concept5


    #ifndef __Concept5__Base__
    #define __Concept5__Base__

    #include <iostream>

    class Base
    {
    public:
         virtual void speak();
    };

    #endif /* defined(__Concept5__Base__) */

    //
    //  Derived.cpp
    //  Concept5


    #include "Derived.h"

    void Derived::speak()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived speaks" << std::endl;
    }

    //
    //  Derived.h
    //  Concept5
    //

    #ifndef __Concept5__Derived__
    #define __Concept5__Derived__

    #include <iostream>
    #include "Base.h"

    class Derived : public Base
    {
    public:
        void speak();
    };
    #endif /* defined(__Concept5__Derived__) */
```

Comment: An update: Before NSTimer fires the _handler type is Derived (expected), but after NSTimer fires the _handler type is Base.

Comment: You have a constructor that takes an address and stores it.  There is no indication what happens or happened to what that address points to in the interim between the init() function and the update() function.  You then test for not NULL in the update function, but that test is worthless if the object that was pointed to is invalid.

Comment: Could it be that derived object created in applicationDidFinishLaunching goes out of scope and is destroyed when applicationDidFinishLaunching finished? And its reference is not retained by the instance of monitor?

Comment: Probably that is the issue.  I posted an answer below, albeit I am not an Objective-C programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Objective-C, but the following looks like an issue:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Derived derived;
    monitor->init(derived);
    //....
}
```

Since `Derived` is a local variable, the scope will not go beyond the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function.  Thus calling `init()` (which takes a pointer), will be holding onto an invalid object when the above function returns.

If this were C++, the solution is to make sure the lifetime of the object is sufficient.  The usual solutions are:

1) Make the object global, or

2) Create the object dynamically using `new`, or

3) Create a smart pointer (probably `std::shared_ptr`) and use that instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Objective-C expert, but EXC_BAD_ACCESS mean you are trying to access something with a bad pointer, likely a nil pointer.

Since your timer is calling an INSTANCE method in stead of a CLASS method on a Monitor instance, you *better* have a monitor instance when your timer fires.  My *guess* is that you don't.  If I was more of an Objective-C person, I could probably look at your code & see this, but as it is I would have to run your code to tell.  But I'd bet that is what is wrong.

That all being said, it is a risky idea to call timers with instance methods, unless you are absolutely sure the instance will still be around & you know what you're doing.  It is safer to only  call class methods on a timer.